# Edit text box in ASP.Net MVC application not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

For reasons currently unknown, in a strongly typed partial view that handles editing which was created using the auto-scaffold for an "Edit" template, refuses to display any data in the textbox.

But, the test titletext string displays the relevent content.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {

try
{
%>

<fieldset>
<legend>Fields</legend>

<p>

<% 
string titletext = Model.Title.ToString();
%>

<%= titletext %>

<label for="Title">Title:</label>
<%= Html.TextBox("Title", Model.Title) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Title", "*") %>

</p>
```

Comment: Refactored the database table column name to QuestionTitle and refactored the partial view
<p>
 <label for="QuestionTitle">Title:</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("QuestionTitle", Model.QuestionTitle)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("QuestionTitle", "*")%>
</p>
and it now works a treat. Thanks! (Still can't understand why Model.Title and Page.Title conflict though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the text you put into the textbox doesn't contain html tags - try to html.encode your text.

In MVC 2 this is handled automagically.

Edit:
Isn't the Model.Title property in conflict with Page-level Title variable?

Comment: Tried <%= Html.TextBox("Title", Html.Encode(Model.Title)) %> and it remains empty. BTW the Title contains purely text.

Comment: Isn't the Model.Title property in conflict with Page-level Title variable? - Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Try to name differently the Title property of the Model. Just try MyTitle for example. In asp.net mvc some names are defined by convention, might be a conflict there.

Comment: There are other property names such as Model.Detail that aren't displaying in the Edit text boxes which display fine elsewhere.

Comment: It is interesting that someone downvote my try to help, but no other answer was added. :(